# Dynamically Set Control Adaptor

Tags: asp.net, dynamic, adapter

In ASP.Net is there a way to dynamically set a control adapter?  The standard way to apply a contol adapter is via the ".browser" files.  However, I have a situation where I would like to use the control adapter in some circumstances, but not in others - and i can not find a way to achieve this.

Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The code you want is:

```
Type controlType = typeof(HtmlForm);
Type adapterType = typeof(MyHtmlFormAdapter);
HttpContext.Current.Request.Browser.Adapters[controlType.AssemblyQualifiedName]
                    = adapterType.AssemblyQualifiedName;
```